# merge rows in a dataframe by id trying to avoid null values in columns (Spark scala)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, row

I am developing in Spark scala, and I would like to merge some rows in a dataframe...

My dataframe is the next one:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|name                     |col1               |col2           |col3                          |
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|                    a    |               null|           null|                      0.000000|
|                    a    |           0.000000|           null|                          null|
|                    b    |               null|           null|                      0.000000|
|                    b    |         300.000000|           null|                          null|
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

And I want to turn on the next dataframe:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|name                     |col1               |col2           |col3                          |
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|                    a    |           0.000000|           null|                      0.000000|
|                    b    |         300.000000|           null|                      0.000000|
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

Having into account:

-Some column can have all values to null.

-There can be a lot of columns in a dataframe.

As far as I know, I have to use the groupBy with the agg(), but I am unable to get the correct expression:

```
df.groupBy("name").agg()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "merge" means sum, column list can be received from dataframe schema and included into "agg":

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", Option.empty[Double], Option.empty[Double], Some(0.000000)),
  ("a", Some(0.000000), Option.empty[Double], Option.empty[Double]),
  ("b", Option.empty[Double], Option.empty[Double], Some(0.000000)),
  ("b", Some(300.000000), Option.empty[Double], Option.empty[Double])
).toDF(
  "name", "col1", "col2", "col3"
)
val columnsToMerge = df
  .columns
  .filterNot(_ == "name")
  .map(c => sum(c).alias(c))

df.groupBy("name")
  .agg(columnsToMerge.head, columnsToMerge.tail: _*)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+----+----+
|name|col1 |col2|col3|
+----+-----+----+----+
|a   |0.0  |null|0.0 |
|b   |300.0|null|0.0 |
+----+-----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `groupby('name')` as you suggest, and then, [ffill() + bfill()](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/what-is-ffill-and-bfill-pandas).

```
df = df.groupby('name').ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

- If you want to keep the name column you can use [pandas update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.groupby('name').ffill().bfill())
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Result df:

| name | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 |  | 0 |
| b | 300 |  | 0 |

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Niv. I am trying this in scala, and not in python. Anyway, I will with a similar approach. Thank you very much!